# How to workaround strict aliasing in C?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

My aim is to make an generic arena allocator with an buffer stored in the `.bss` section of the executable to avoid any allocations in the actual program, however this has problems in C with strict aliasing. If I define the buffer as `static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];`, then by strict aliasing I can't use pointers to it that are of another type without causing undefined behavior. As I want this allocator to be generic, so I need to be able to allocate any type in it.

I can't use `memcpy()` because the allocator needs to return a pointer that can be used in any way, not an copy of the value. I also cannot use union-based type punning because, if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't work through pointers (see the second code block [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing)).

The only way that I know to work around this in C is to disable strict aliasing entirely with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag. In [this blog post](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2023/09/27/#pointer-laundering-filthy-hack) the author attempts to do the same thing, but the solution he arrives is to use inline assembly to "launder" the pointer so that the optimizer can't apply the strict aliasing optimization, but this seems very fragile.

Is there any better way to do something like this? Ideally there would be an builtin that allows to clearly mark a cast or region of memory to be ignored by strict aliasing.

Comment: I thought `char` was [exempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/14637) from the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but only if it is the type using for accessing, not the original type. You can alias a `float*` with a `char*` but not the other way around, which is what I'm doing here. In fact the answer you linked explains this: "[...] However this won't work the other way: there's no assumption that your struct aliases a buffer of chars."

Comment: That gcc link with a pointer access seems to describe a non-conforming compiler. A conforming compiler has to follow C17 6.7.2.1 §16, emphasis mine: "_The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), **and
vice versa**._" If the compiler is assuming that an `int*` cannot be used to access a union containing a `int` member, it is then breaking the above requirement from the C standard.

Comment: Additionally, the "strict aliasing rule" (6.5) itself is corresponding to the above requirement. _"An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:.. /-/ ... "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types [a type compatible with the effective type of the object] among its members"_

Comment: It may be that the gcc docs are confusing C behavior and C++ behavior. In general, the gcc docs have a nasty reputation, not to be trusted. Unless the actual compiler (gcc in C mode) does behave as the documentation says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the allocation code in a separate module or modules from the code using it (the client code). Then, as long as you are building with traditional compilers and linkers that do not perform cross-module optimization, aliasing necessarily works due to the separate-module nature of the build tools rather than due to the requirements of the C standard. (The allocation code itself needs to observe the aliasing rules.)

The reason this works is that when compiling some client code of the allocation routines, the compiler sees only the client code and not the allocation code. It cannot know the declared type used by the allocation code. After you compile the client code, you could link it with your allocation routines or you could, hypothetically, link it with some other code in which all the addresses returned by the allocation code have declared types matching their uses or with some other code in which all the addresses returned by the allocation code are provided by the `malloc` defined by the C standard rather than your own code. Since the client code **could** be linked with this other code, the compiler must generate an object module that works with it as specified by the C standard. However, the behavior of your allocation code and the behavior of this other code are identical in the view of the interfaces between them: The client code calls an allocation routine and receives a pointer or it calls a release routine and provides a pointer, and so on. Therefore, when the compiler generates code that works with the other standard-conforming code, it must also work with your actual allocation code.

Comment: This is really ingenious! I feel like this still falls under "tricking the compiler" territory just like the inline assembly way, but it feels much more resilient and portable. A problem with this is that it requires you to have more than one translation unit and I guess not do LTO when linking this module, which adds complexity to the build.

Comment: In some cases, having an allocation library keep a copy of the last freed object and using it to satisfy the next allocation request can be a useful optimization, and the benefits can be increased by using LTO; this may fail if one doesn't use `-fno-strict-aliasing`, but the benefits from LTO may exceed the cost of `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: "as long as you are building with traditional compilers and linkers that do not perform cross-module optimization" - this is increasingly hard to ensure with modern toolchains.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: While not officially acknowledged by the "standard", the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag is more widely supported and reliable than any alternative constructs other than forcibly separating compilation units and blocking link-time optimization, and the performance costs of `-fno-strict-aliasing` will often be less than imposed by opaque function calls.

Use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag with clang or gcc, without apology.  That's the most portable and reliable way to make such code work.  According to the published Rationale, the authors of the C Standard *intended* that implementations would--on a "quality of implementation" basis--extend the semantics of the language by specifying the behavior of more constructs and corner cases than mandated by the Standard, in cases where doing so would be useful.  They sought to give programmers a "fighting chance" [their words!] to write portable programs, but never intended that programmers jump through hoops to ensure portability except when their code had to be usable on a particular implementation *that couldn't otherwise support it*.  Writing code to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` without any compiler-specific syntax for laundering will yield a program which is compatible with any compiler that has a mode equivalent to `-fno-strict-aliasing`, i.e. almost any general-purpose C compiler on the planet.

If one doesn't use `-fno-strict-aliasing`, some parts of the clang or gcc optimizers may transform code whose behavior the Standard was intended to define, into code which downstream optimizations fail to process meaningfully.  If, for example, some code happens to read a value using a 64-bit `long`, reuses the storage as a 64-bit `long long`, and later uses a `long long` to write a value that is numerically the same as the `long` that was read, clang and gcc may treat the latter action as reverting the Effective Type of the storage to `long`.  Although clang or gcc wouldn't recognize or do anything weird with the vast majority of situations where a value that's written to storage using one type happens to match a value that had been read using a different type, the Standard makes no distinction between cases where they wouldn't apply such transforms and cases where they demonstrably apply it in ways that break things.

While it's possible to write some constructs in "optimization-proof" fashion, doing so will often result in machine code that's less efficient than what could be achieved using `-fno-strict-aliasing`, and the range of situations where quirks in future versions of clang and gcc might break things would be reduced.

Comment: The problem with open source compilers is that they don't seem to have any ambition to become/remain a quality implementation. Commercial compilers have this ambition since they want to have customers. Whereas the open source compilers are content to be a "ISO compliant Death Station", because they have access to lots of language-lawyers, but not so much to people using the compiler in a non-PC context such as embedded systems, where the strict aliasing rules make no sense, neither as written nor as intended.

Comment: For example, strict aliasing rationales often make an example where a function taking a `int*` parameter should be able to assume that this pointer isn't accessing some external linkage `double` and vice versa. However, not even this rationale is sensible. ->

Comment: There are plenty of embedded systems where you have a need to store generic data in data flash/eeprom or serialize/deserialize data to be sent over various busses. There will be some manner of alignment and endianess requirements not necessarily the same as the fundamental alignment of the CPU. It might need to work with byte streams. So there is always a need to access variables used for this kind of hardware-related programming through another type than the declared type. This is how computer hardware works. The ISO C WG needs to acknowledge this eventually.

Comment: @Lundin: You have the Rationale's types backward: the function took a `double*` parameter and accessed it as well as a stand-alone `int` object, which would only make sense on platforms where `int` was at least as big as `double`.  What's really needed is to recognize that the rule was only intended to allow compilers to assume things wouldn't alias when there was no particular evidence that they might.  If compilers made a good faith effort to notice such evidence, that would be sufficient for 99% of cases, and if programmers made sure to supply evidence in cases compilers might miss...

Comment: ...that could take care of the rest.  The extremely vast majority of cases that presently require `-fno-strict-aliasing` do so because the authors of clang and gcc are using the Standard as an excuse to be incompatible with well established constructs that compilers had essentially unanimously supported identically before.

Comment: I wouldn't say that clang and gcc have no ambition to be "quality implementations", so much as it is that the authors misinterpret the Standard as defining an idealized form of the language to which all programs should aspire, rather than a minimal form that even the lowest quality compilers must accept, and thus think that they can improve the language if they discourage the use of "non-portable" constructs.  Treating an access to `*(unsigned*)floatPtr` as a potential access to a `float` wouldn't be difficult, nor would it degrade the performance of any non-contrived programs, but it would...

Comment: @Lundin: (see above) ...acknowledge the legitimacy of performing type punning in that fashion, rather than using "portable" approaches like unions which--not coincidentally--they process more efficiently than many commercial compilers (which instead focus on processing the more straightforwardly-written code correctly).

Comment: "think that they can improve the language if they discourage the use of "non-portable" constructs" Seriously? To me it rather seems that some new, completely useless GNU extension is released every week or so. Ideally in direct conflict with requirements of how strictly conforming programs should behave, in order to repeatedly remove the programmers' confidence in using the tool in any professional context. Last stable release was gcc version 7 or something. It's a sad state of affairs.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not saying the maintainers of clang and gcc are consistent in their philosophy, but the opposition to supporting idiomatic type punning constructs seems to be driven by ideology more than a desire to maximize usefulness.